# how to combine rows of the same table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Imagine that I have these Table

```
Name       Type       JobName  Desc
first      SMARt      first    the main first 
first      SufFold    second   the second, depend on first
```

I need to generate, all subfold but including description of their name that like you see is in another row.

```
Name       JobName     Desc              Desc2
first      second      the main fisrt    the second, depend on first
```

I'm trying with iner join of the same table but I have a lot of duplicates. Anyone could help me plese? Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the query you're using so you can get help fixing it. The "Name" column is unique, right?

Comment: Do you have a numeric column not shown which can provide the ordering you expect?

Comment: @Mat. Name is not unique. You can see that I have 2 rows with same value

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't have numeric column, but I don't understand what do you means with the ordering I expect.?

Comment: Of course, but you don't have multiple (name=first,jobname=first) entries?

Comment: @Mat correct, is like SMART is the father and have sons that are the SubFold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the same table to connect parent with children, and then display description from two (same) tables.
Since you gave no informations about how tables are connected i wrote example of pseudo code how it could look like:

```
SELECT t1.name
       ,t1.jobName
       ,t1.Desc
       ,tChild.Desc as Desc2 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table1 tChild on t1.id=tChild.parent_id
```